# Set Hibernate Session to Read Only for Whole Application

Tags: java, hibernate, session, grails

I know you can set a session to create "read only" objects by calling setDefaultReadOnly on the session.  However, I'm trying to accomplish this for the whole application so that I don't have to set the session to read only every time I interact with it.

Also just to clarify, setting the session to read only doesn't set the connection to read only, it simply disables auto commit and dirty checking for the objects created by the session.  This is exactly what I'm after.

Ideally I'm trying to accomplish this in Grails, however, if anyone knows how to do this in Hibernate in general I should be able to port that over to Grails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible in grails since 2.3.0 version. See [here](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10064)